# No Wifi on Toshiba Satellite L50t-B

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom

I tried Install Broadcom Drivers thread from 8 years ago but still not connected via Wifi. Ethernet connection works fine. 
I worked my way through the whole tutorial.  My wifi card is ver 14e44365 rev 01. The sudo-apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source command said OK but mod probe error could not insert 'wl'? I continued with putting on B43 firmware installer which was OK and then reinstated the driver with sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-bowl (step 3) but still no connections.
I am a newbie so need clear instructions if anyone has any ideas. Many thanks

Comment: You may need to disable Secure Boot.

Comment: Thank you, how do I do that?

Comment: It should be a selectable option in your computers BIOS/EFI.